# Number of right isosceles triangles in a rectangular grid

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

How to count efficiently the number of right isosceles triangles in a nxm rectangular grid?

- The 3 corners of the triangles must have integer coordinates.
- The right sides of the triangles are not necessarily parallel to grid lines.

Comment: There are 0 (zero) right isosceles triangles in a rectangular grid. Perhaps you mean the number of right isosceles triangles that can be formed from the points in a rectangular grid - but you need to show some effort. Also, given that it's a rectangular grid, not a square one, are the grid points spaced uniformly along either axis, both, or none? I'm not sure there's an easy answer without a more specific  problem statement, and there may not be one in the general case, anyway...

Comment: Wow. Hundreds!! As well as all the obvious ones, you have loads like (0,0),(2,4),(3,1)

Comment: Obviously, the grid points are spaced uniformly along both axis. the coordinates of the bottom left corner of the grid are (0,0) and those of the top right corner are (n,m). I need the number of right isoceles triangles for given n,m values. I know there is a solution in O(n*m) but I need a more efficient solution.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396570/what-is-an-efficient-algorithm-for-counting-the-number-of-triangles-in-a-graph

Comment: @Spevy: Not a duplicate of it. And I don't think we can use graphs here. It belongs to maths, geometry, and algorithms.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths, not programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let A be the triangle's corner where the right angle is located. Let ab be the difference vector to the first corner and ac the difference vector to the other corner. ac should always be left of ab. So for a given ab, we can calculate ac as:

```
ac = (-ab.y, ab.x)
```

So there are only two integer degrees of freedom for a certain triangle, given A. We can calculate the possible intervals for ab as:

```
A.x + ab.x >= 0   -->  ab.x >= -A.x
A.x + ab.x <= m   -->  ab.x <= m - A.x
A.y + ab.x >= 0   -->  ab.x >= -A.y
A.y + ab.x <= n   -->  ab.x <= n - A.y

A.y + ab.y >= 0   -->  ab.y >= -A.y
A.y + ab.y <= n   -->  ab.y <= n - A.y
A.x - ab.y >= 0   -->  ab.y <= A.x
A.x - ab.y <= m   -->  ab.y >= A.x - m
```

So the possible intervals are

```
xmin = max(-A.x, -A.y)
xmax = min(m - A.x, n - A.y)
ymin = max(-A.y, A.x - m)
ymax = min(n - A.y, A.x)
```

The number of possible vectors that fulfil these conditions (except the 0-vector) are:

```
c = (xmax - xmin + 1) * (ymax - ymin + 1) - 1
```

The desired result is the sum of c for all possible `A` within the grid. With the naive approach you get an `O(grid cells)` runtime. Depending on your grid, this could already be fast enough.

### Update

In order to split the sum of `c` (over all grid cells) we must determine where the results of the `max` and `min` operations change. E.g. `ymax` changes as follows:

[image: Grid 1]

Note that I have offset the line a bit to the right, so there is a unique mapping from points to the regions the points belong to.

When we do this for all interval boundaries, we get the following picture (for m > n):

[image: Grid 2]

Now we can calculate the sum of `c` for each region independently. I'll show that exemplarily for the left most triangle region.

For that region the following conditions hold:

```
xmin = -A.y
xmax = n - A.y
ymin = -A.y
ymax = A.x

c(x, y) = (n - y + x) * (x + y) - 1
        = (nx + ny - y^2 + x^2 - 1)
```

Now we sum that for all `x`s and `y`s in that region. `x` runs from 0 through `n/2`. `y` runs from `x` to `n-x`.

So we get:

```
                n/2  n-x
sumLeftRegion = Sum  Sum  (nx + ny - y² + x² - 1) 
                x=0  y=x
```

We can solve this (e.g. using your favorite algebra program and get:

```
sumLeftRegion = 1/48 * (2 + n)*(-24 - 14n + 6n^2 + 5n^3)
```

This can be done for all other regions. You would need some few cases (i.e. `m > n`, `m = n`, `m < n`, probably even and odd `n` and `m`). The case `n > m` can be converted to `m > n` by rotating the grid (which does not change the number of possible triangles). It'll be some work, but in the end you get the result in `O(1)` because there will be no iterations.

Comment: Your solution belong exactly for the problem in O(grid cells). I need more explanations for the improvement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added more explanations on the improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Consider RAIT ABC. If we maintain a corner (A) of the triangle at (0,0), then we can say that for a every positive point (B) along y=1 (so (1,1),(2,1),etc a RAIT exists whose other corner (C) is at (n,n), where Cn = Bx-1.  It should be obvious that must also be true for y=2 (starting from B(2,2), y=3 (starting from B(3,3), etc. - you're just doubling, tripling, etc. the cooordinates. Does that help? (I'm no mathematician - in case that's not obvious)

Answer (score 0):

Consider any triangle in the box. It has a unique bounding box (in the sense that it only has one, not that it's the only triangle with that bounding box). So, if you consider every possible bounding box side lengths, `(i,j)`, and count the number of RAIT triangles with this bounding box, (denote this `CP(i,j)`) then your answer is `sum(i=1 to n, sum(j=1 to m,CP(i,j)*(m-j+1))*(n-i+1))`. The `(m-j+1)*(n-i+1)` is counting how many of that size box can fit in the  `n*m` box. So the hard part now is to find `CP(i,j)`. Again, `CP(i,j)` is the number of RAIT triangles with points on the perimeter of the box with lengths `i` and `j`. We can use symmetry to our advantage here. Assume with no loss of generality that the right angle is ABC. Imagine the triangle being aligned with the positive axes.

```
A 
|\
| \
B__C
```

Now consider rotating it clockwise until it lines back up with itself. There are two possibilities through that process: BC is in quadrants 1 and 2 or in quadrants 3 and 4.

```
2|1
---
3|4
```

What we notice here is that in the first case B lies along the bottom or right of the bounding box, and in the second case B lies along the top or left of the bounding box. So wlog we assume that B lies along the bottom or right, excluding the very bottom left corner.

```
+-----*
|     *
|     *
+******
```

Once we calculate how many RAIT triangles have this property we can just double it!
If B is at the top right corner, then there is just one triangle to test for RAIT-ness, same if it's in the bottom right corner. If it's along the right wall, then there are i triangles to check (placing C at each point along the top, and calculating the third point to see if it forms the given bounding box). Similarly, if it's along the bottom wall, then there are j triangles to check.

This is definitely worse than O(m*n), it's probably somewhere around O(m^2*n^2), but hopefully this helps somehow.

EDIT

We can actually do a little better in our testing triangles. With a little geometric intuition, we can see that if B is along the bottom, and closer to the bottom right corner, then C is in the top right corner. Similarly if it's closer to the bottom left corner, then A is in the top right corner. So we can just consider half of B's positions, and for each position we only need to consider one possible triangle. (The argument when B is on the right is similar).