# How to find number of triangles in a given undirected graph?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, graph-theory

I have a undirected graph, and I wanted to count or list the triangles existing in the Graph.

Comment: What have you already researched?

Comment: The naïve solution is O(v^3), which is (close to) an optimal asymptotic upper bound on the worst case. It's dumb for sparse graphs, but for highly connected graphs its overhead isn't bad. If you're interested and don't know what I'm hinting at, let me know and I'll add an answer. Come to think of it, you can implement something quite similar with is O(e^3) and which is great for sparse graphs, and dumb for highly-connected graphs. Only when |E| ~= |V| does the naïve method do bad compared to something more complicated.

Comment: This is a really famous graph problem that's been attracting a bunch of research recently. Have you done any searches to see what's out there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an efficient algorithm for counting the number of triangles in a graph?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396570/what-is-an-efficient-algorithm-for-counting-the-number-of-triangles-in-a-graph)