# is there any fast algorithm to calculate eigenvalue of a n*n matrix?n may be as large as 100000

Tags: algorithm, matrix, matrix-multiplication, adjacency-matrix, eigenvalue

here a input is a matrix

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int matrix[n][n]={0};
for(j=0;j<no_edges;j++) //no_edges----max edges in the matrix
{
 cin>>row>>col;
 matrix[row][col]=1;
 matrix[col][row]=1;
}
eigen(matrix);
}
eigen(matrix[][])
{
 //defination?????
}
```

here all the inputs of the matrix n*n is either 1 or 0...
    n=3
    also matrix is  symmetrical along its diagonal and has 0 value in its    diagonal={(0,1,0);(1,0,1);(0,1,0)}.Also i think performance can be improved using adjacency list...But how to multiply a adjacency list as awe do in adjacency matrix?

Comment: Since your matrix is symmetric, you can use SVD to get the eigenvalues. [SuiteSparse](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html) has some efficient implementations for sparse matrices.

Comment: Are you using this to compute some feature of a graph?  If so, does your graph have any special structure and which feature are you trying to compute?

Comment: total no of different triangles in a graph

Comment: There may be some useful answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396570/what-is-an-efficient-algorithm-for-counting-the-number-of-triangles-in-a-graph but it looks like this is hard unless you have some special structure (such as a sparse graph).