# Amount of triangles we can build

Tags: algorithm

We are given `n` segments - each of some given length. All of these segments form a one stick. We can break this stick only between some segments.

Now we want to know how many divisions of the stick into three parts are there, that form a triangle. So we break stick in two places, sum the lengths of segments of each part and we check if they form a triangle.

For example: for `6` segments of lengths `1 2 3 4 5 6` we can form two triangles `1 2 3 | 4 5 | 6` or `1 2 3 4 | 5 | 6`.

For `8` segments: `1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21` there can be `3` triangles.

I need to count amount of these triangles in the best possible time complexity. I am thinking of making some partial sums and then binary search? But not sure about the details.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Looks like an interesting coding interview puzzle. Don't let us rob you of this learning experience.

Comment: Your input seems to be an undirected graph - a long line formed by concatenation of long list of edges. For undirected graphs, I think we can't do better than O(n^3). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396570/what-is-an-efficient-algorithm-for-counting-the-number-of-triangles-in-a-graph)

Comment: Do they need to be successive? What i mean : `1 2 3 | 4 6 | 5` is this sequence valid?